# PIL - error whilst installing openerp

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-imaging-library, openerp-7

Greatings...

Although I dont think one is caused by the other - whilst installing openerp 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 server, using  `sudo python setup.py install` I get a PIL error

> Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20160502-py2.7.egg
>   Processing dependencies for openerp==7.0-20160502
>   Searching for PIL
>   Reading http://download.gna.org/pychart/
>   Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/PIL/
>   No local packages or download links found for PIL
>   error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('PIL')

I had the same problem when using ubuntu 16 and openerp 7 hence the attempt with 14 :(

When you follow the link `https://pypi.python.org/simple/PIL/` ubuntus correct theres no Links. I assume this is the problem.

Any help or direction greatly appreciated - running out of hair :((

Comment: Have you tried following answer ?

Comment: IMO don't use `sudo` with `pip` instead use `sudo apt install python-pil` or use `pip install --user <my-packages>` after making sure dependencies of `<my-packages>` are met (see [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37203465/1020470))

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me, 
I solved this way

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev
```

And try there installing via `pip install PIL`.

More on what `pip` is can be found [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html). In short is a convenient (and becoming a standard) way of installing python libraries.

if it continues to fail, it can be due to PIL searching those libraries in a different path.

> It turns out that the APT installations put the libraries under **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu** and PIL will search for them in **/usr/lib/**.
>   So you have to create symlinks for PIL to see them.

Try to see if libjpeg and libz libs exist in **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu** and make a symlink this way

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 /lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 /usr/lib/
```

---

**Source:** http://jj.isgeek.net/2011/09/install-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-ubuntu-oneiric-64bits/